# How to Scaffold Razor Pages using CLI?

Tags: razor, scaffolding, asp.net-core-2.0

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model) shows the implementation of `Razor Pages` in `Asp.Net Core 2`. However, when I run my `CLI` command:

```
 dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m PatReg -dc ArtCoreDbContext
 -udl -outDir Pages\--referenceScriptLibraries
```

The output looks like below

[image]

I have the following ref-packages in my project.cs,

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Composition" Version="1.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ASPSMS" Version="0.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Composition" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Am I missing a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I was missing a reference.
I updated all packages and added

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Final `.csproj` looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <UserSecretsId>--------------------------</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Composition" Version="1.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the project folder, run the following two commands.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

dotnet build
```

Reference: https://gavilan.blog/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-2-doing-scaffolding-with-dotnet-cli-aspnet-codegenerator/